# Strange metrics for endpoints that don't exist in Spring Boot app in production

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that I just launched into initial beta/production like environment. It is externally accessible. I've been watching the actuator metrics to get a sense for how well it's handling the load it's getting (which is great btw). After this recent weekend, I noticed some new counter.status and gauge.response "endpoints" showing up as if someone external is hitting some endpoint that I did not create in my application. I have two main endpoints and these strange one's I'm seeing do not make any sense to me. My question is, is this someone/something external scanning my system for vulnerabilities?

```javascript
   "counter.status.200.services.rest": 1,
   "counter.status.200.v1.0.109306535771.activities": 2,
   "counter.status.200.v2.0.1493038024241481.activities": 3,
   "counter.status.200.v2.0.320114888083932.activities": 2,
   "counter.status.200.v2.1.477822048999402.activities": 1,
   "counter.status.200.v2.2.477822048999402.activities": 9,

   "gauge.response.100001810876627.root": 0,
   "gauge.response.1384415981.root": 1,
   "gauge.response.381050928725826.activities": 5,
   "gauge.response.503898666.contacts.addressbook.root": 0,
   "gauge.response.503898666.root": 1,
   "gauge.response.617072928356658.activities": 427,
```

Comment: It is neither clear which requests were made nor does your question give any information about the real problem. One could any speculate about the strage behavior like automated port scans, google site lookups, etc.

Comment: The counter status is 200 - so it is successfully returning these responses. Can you increase logging and call these urls?